# Could not cast value of type - Objective C NSManagedObject in Swift

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift

I've found numerous posts about this error being able to resolve by adding the prefix of the project name to the class in entity viewer e.g ProjectName.Journey also the suggestion of adding @objc(ClassName) above the class declaration. But these solutions don't work for me. The problem is I have a NSManagedObject class generated in Objective C that I then try to access in Swift. I get the following error:

```
Unable to load class named 'ProjectName.Journey' for entity 'Journey'.  Class not found, using default NSManagedObject instead.
Could not cast value of type 'NSManagedObject_Journey_' (0x1700541f0) to 'Journey' (0x100096f38).
```

My Class:
H:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreData/CoreData.h>


@interface Journey : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * travelMode;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * startTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * endTime;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * averageSpeed;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * distance;

@end
```

M:

```
#import "Journey.h"

@implementation Journey

@dynamic travelMode;
@dynamic startTime;
@dynamic endTime;
@dynamic averageSpeed;
@dynamic distance;

@end
```

My code trying to access this code in Swift:

```
for res in results {
  var move: Journey = res as! Journey; //error thrown here
  var morningStamp = midnightDate!.timeIntervalSince1970;
  var eveningStamp = morningStamp + 86400;
  if(move.startTime.timeIntervalSince1970 > morningStamp) { 
    if(move.endTime.timeIntervalSince1970 < eveningStamp)     {
      filtered.addObject(move);
    }
   }
}
```

bridge header file:

```
//
//  Use this file to import your target's public headers that you would like to expose to Swift.
//

#import "TravelRecordManager.h"
#import "Journey.h"
```

Comment: Have you created the bridging header file?

Comment: Yep, updated to show header file ^

Comment: And the project file references that header, right?